# Strange Calculator

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

I found this Strange Calculator, and I don't know how it works.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Strange Calculator]

I've run some problems through it and here are the results:
$$\begin{array}\
&A+B = 23 & F-G = -1 & K\times L = 156\\
&B+C = 25 & G-H = -1 & L \times M = 182\\
&C+D = 27 & H-I = -1 & M \times N = 210\\
&D+E = 29 & I-J = -1 & N \times O = 240\\
&E+F = 22 & J-K = -1 & O \times P = 128\\
\\
&\frac{P}Q = 0.8888888888888888 & \frac{Q}R = 0.9&\\
&\frac{R}S = 0.9090909090909091 & \frac{S}T = 0.9166666666666666&\\
&\frac{T}U = 0.9230769230769231 \\
\\
&U^V = 3937376385699289 & V^W = 155568095557812224&\\
&W^X = 6568408355712890625 &X^Y = 295147905179352825856&\\
&Y^Z = 118587876497 \\
\end{array}
$$

> **EDIT** corrected precision issue. Thanks to @f'' !

If I need to supply more calculations, let me know what you'd like! (One per customer, please)

I'd like to know:

> What values do the letters represent?
>   How were they derived?

I had a link to the actual **Flash Calculator**, and wanted to supply it to you so that you could do your own experiments, but I can't find it right now.
Maybe It'll turn up eventually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A=11
> B=12
> C=13
> D=14
> E=15
> F=7
> G=8
> H=9
> I=10
> J=11
> K=12
> L=13
> M=14
> N=15
> O=16
> P=8
> Q=9
> R=10
> S=11
> T=12
> U=13
> V=14
> W-Z seem to be slightly different. Working on it!

Not sure how they were derived yet, just noticed that:

> P/Q = 8/9, and 128 is divisible by 8. The rest I worked out from there

Courtesy of f'' (last few and derivation)

> W=15
> X=16
> Y=17
> Z=9
> Each is the sum of the digits in the decimal ASCII value for the capital letter

Comment: WXY are 15-17, but the calculator must have run out of precision.

Answer (score 0):

A=23-B
C=25-B......K=B
L= 156/B and M=7B/6

Now B should be Multiple of 6

Going further
N=180/B
Now B should be factor of 180 and multiple of 6 
**So B could be (6,12,18,30,45 or 90)**

P=96/B
Now B should be factor of 96 and multiple of 6
So now the remaining possible values of B are 6 or 12

Values of B are **B=6 or B=12**

Going further
Q would be 9 (if B is 12) or 18(if B is 6)
R would be 10 or 12...
U would be 13 or 26
Now V can be derived only from 13 not from 26. So we can easily ignore B=6

Now the final value of **B = 12** and rest of the values are given below.

A=11
C=13
D=14
E=15
F=7
G=8
H=9
I=10
J=11
K=12
L=13
M=14
N=15
O=16
P=8
Q=9
R=10
S=11
T=12
U=13
V=14
W=15
X=16
Y=17
Z=9